# How can I make a trial version of a windows application?

Tags: registry, trial

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create trial version of .NET software?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423976/how-to-create-trial-version-of-net-software)

I made a Windows application and I want to distribute it as a trial version. How can I add a timer to it so that the software stops working after a fixed period of time?

Also, in the registry,my trial days are being counted.  Will my users be able to delete the registry files and  circumvent the trial limitations?

Comment: Based on your history .net? ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423976/how-to-create-trial-version-of-net-software

Comment: @Alex K - Well after trail can users edit the registry to use it for life time?